# Installing cassandra on RHEL using docker

Tags: docker, cassandra-2.0

I am trying to install cassandra on RHEL-7 from source code using docker.
I have done following steps inside the container:

```
1 - yum install -y git java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel ant
2- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0
3- export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
4- export ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
5- export PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
6- export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
7 -git clone https://github.com/apache/cassandra.git
8 -cd cassandra && ant
```

The build is successful. But when I try to start cassandra server inside container I am getting following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
Internal Error (cppInterpreter_zero.cpp:812), pid=836, tid=4397984807184
Error: Unimplemented()
```

Any idea?

Comment: slight off-topic: is there any reason you didn't go with docker's own cassandra image? https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/

Comment: there was the most stupid error.. I had to clone the stable branch of cassandra to make it work. So now I am using git clone -b cassandra-2.1 https://github.com/apache/cassandra.git